# R Data Frames: Working with rows containing multiple values in one or more columns

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot-table, flatten

I am working with a data set that has multiple values in several columns for each row.

I need to be able to run basic stats on this data, such as summaries and crosstabs.

**About the Values**

1. Each value is seperated with a comma, none are numeric.
2. There can be zero to three values in the example. Real world is zero to many options (I think 8 is the max I have seen so far)
3. In some cases, at least one of the columns has repeats of the same value (e.g. "Filter,Gear,Filter")

Note: In cases where a row has multiples of the same value in a column, for analysis purposes they should be made unique (e.g. "Filter,Gear<strike>,Filter</strike>")

**Mock Data Example**

```
df.orig <- structure(list(id = 1:5, Part = structure(c(4L, 16L, 11L, 5L, 
    19L), levels = c("Gear", "Gear,Gear", "Rocker", "", 
    "Piston,Hose,Piston", "Piston,Cam,Lamp", 
    "Chain,Cam,Plug", "Compressor,Pan,Cam", "Belt", "Belt,Chain", 
    "Cap,AC,Cam", "Heater", "Blade,Heater", "Plug,Filter,Filter", 
    "Bolt,Piston", "Gauge,Gauge,Bolt", "Chain,Piston,Bar", 
    "Fluid,Pan,Fluid", "Fluid,Fuse,Bolt", "Lamp"), class = "factor"), 
    Achievements = structure(c(11L, 12L, 9L, 8L, 5L), levels = c("Award,Badge,Plaque", 
    "Award,Cetificate,Plaque", "Award,Plaque,Plaque", "Badge", 
    "Badge,Badge,Cetificate", "Badge,Pin,Award", "Cetificate", 
    "Cetificate,Badge,Plaque", "Pin,Plaque,Badge", "Pin,Plaque,Plaque", 
    "Plaque", "Plaque,Award,Cetificate", "Plaque,Badge,Plaque", 
    "Plaque,Pin,Award"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), 
    class = "data.frame")
```

What is the best method to manipulate those columns for easy analysis in R?

Is it to split on the comma, so that it creates multiple columns (as per df example below). Or is it to keep the data together with the separator (as per df above) and use R tools to do the heavy lifting?

**Split on Comma**

```
df.split <- structure(list(id = 1:5, Part_1 = c("", "Gauge", "Cap", "Piston", 
    "Fluid"), Part_2 = c("", "Gauge", "AC", "Hose", "Fuse"), Part_3 = c("", 
    "Bolt", "Cam", "Piston", "Bolt"), Ach_1 = c("Plaque", "Plaque", 
    "Pin", "Cetificate", "Badge"), Ach_2 = c("", "Award", "Plaque", 
    "Badge", "Badge"), Ach_3 = c("", "Cetificate", "Badge", "Plaque", "Cetificate")), 
    class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

If it is split into new columns, in my mind I am foreseeing multiple subsets, or loops and uniqued arrays to cycle though each row of data, prior to analysis. However, there may be better R packages to handle what I need to do.

I am not sure:

1. What are the best practices here for structuring the df in R?
2. What R packages are best suited to manipulating the data before running stats tools on them?

Any assitance or direction to detailed documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: (Note: you have `factor`s, not strings, so some operations may not behave as expected.)

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions and notes! I am going to test them out to see what works best for the stats I need.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to organize this data frame is in *long format*. The tidyverse functions `pivot_longer`, `mutate` and `unnest` will help you here:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df.new <- df.orig %>%
  pivot_longer(Part:Achievements) %>%
  mutate(value = strsplit(as.character(value), ",")) %>%
  unnest(value) %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  summarize(value = unique(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

This gives you

```r
df.new
#>    id         name      value
#> 1   1 Achievements     Plaque
#> 2   2 Achievements     Plaque
#> 3   2 Achievements      Award
#> 4   2 Achievements Cetificate
#> 5   2         Part      Gauge
#> 6   2         Part       Bolt
#> 7   3 Achievements        Pin
#> 8   3 Achievements     Plaque
#> 9   3 Achievements      Badge
#> 10  3         Part        Cap
#> 11  3         Part         AC
#> 12  3         Part        Cam
#> 13  4 Achievements Cetificate
#> 14  4 Achievements      Badge
#> 15  4 Achievements     Plaque
#> 16  4         Part     Piston
#> 17  4         Part       Hose
#> 18  5 Achievements      Badge
#> 19  5 Achievements Cetificate
#> 20  5         Part      Fluid
#> 21  5         Part       Fuse
#> 22  5         Part       Bolt
```

and

```r
table(df.new$name, df.new$value)
              
#>                AC Award Badge Bolt Cam Cap Cetificate Fluid Fuse Gauge Hose Pin Piston Plaque
#>   Achievements  0     1     3    0   0   0          3     0    0     0    0   1      0      4
#>   Part          1     0     0    2   1   1          0     1    1     1    1   0      1      0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I am working with this method today. It certainly makes a frequencies a lot easier given that I can also just select based on a specific value in the name column. 
`df.rev %>% tabyl(name, value) %>% filter(name == "Part")`
Next step is to be able to filter like this for crosstab, but to me, that is where the `id`becomes the key. So something like:
Select rows vals = Achievments; Select row vals = Parts; Match on`id` and create a cross tab of Achievements / Parts. Case `id = 5`would record an instance in Badge/Fluid, Badge/Fuse, Badge/Bolt, Cert/Fuild,  Cert/Fuse & Cert/Bolt

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option if you want it in wide format, where we turn each cell into a vector using `str_split`. Then, we can use `map` to keep only the unique values for each cell. Then, we can use `unnest_wider` to put it into the wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df.orig %>%
    mutate(across(-id, ~ map(str_split(.x, ","), ~ unique(.x)))) %>%
    unnest_wider(-id, names_sep = "_")
```

**Output**

```
     id Part_1   Part_2 Part_3 Achievements_1 Achievements_2 Achievements_3
  <int> <chr>    <chr>  <chr>  <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
1     1          NA     NA     Plaque         NA             NA            
2     2 Gauge    Bolt   NA     Plaque         Award          Cetificate    
3     3 Cap      AC     Cam    Pin            Plaque         Badge         
4     4 Piston   Hose   NA     Cetificate     Badge          Plaque        
5     5 Fluid    Fuse   Bolt   Badge          Cetificate     NA
```

Comment: My only hiccup with trying this out was that my actual data was still tbl_df format and not a data.frame. Once I figured that out, it worked as expected to reformat the rows into wide format.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution that converts it to wide format. you could then apply rowwise functions across groups different variables.

```
df.orig[df.orig==""]<-NA # NA instead of whitespace is needed here
new_df <- data.frame(id=df.orig$id) # new empty dataset

for(v in c("Part","Achievements")){
  #separate commas
  com_spl <- strsplit(as.character(df.orig[,v]), ",") #split strings
  spl_df  <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, com_spl) #create df.orig of split strings list
  names(spl_df) <- paste0(v,1:ncol(spl_df)) #rename variables

  #remove duplicates
  dupes <- t(apply(spl_df,1,duplicated)) # boolean dataframe of duplicates
  dup_idx <- which(dupes==T,arr.ind=T)  #location of duplicates
  spl_df[dup_idx] <- NA #remove duplicates

  #combine
  new_df <- cbind(new_df,spl_df) #add new vars to df.orig
}

#then e.g. unlist(new_df[2,grep("Achievements",names(new_df))])
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

I wanted to update this given I have been working with the methods suggested for part of the work I am doing.

However, there is another df modification that I have had to use to recode  categorical responses. There may be another way to do this, but I went with `mutate` to split a variable into multiple columns for each of the variable's values. Each answer receives its own column and variable name with a 1, 0 or NA.

Here is an example for the Part variable:

```
df.recode <- df.orig %>%
mutate(
Part_Gauge = if_else(str_detect(Part, "Gauge"), 1, 0),
Part_Cap = if_else(str_detect(Part, "Cap"), 1, 0),
Part_AC = if_else(str_detect(Part, "AC"), 1, 0),
Part_Bolt = if_else(str_detect(Part, "Bolt"), 1, 0),
Part_Cam = if_else(str_detect(Part, "Cam"), 1, 0),
Part_Fluid = if_else(str_detect(Part, "Fluid"), 1, 0),
Part_Fuse = if_else(str_detect(Part, "Fuse"), 1, 0),
Part_Hose = if_else(str_detect(Part, "Hose"), 1, 0),
Part_Piston = if_else(str_detect(Part, "Piston"), 1, 0))
```

Note: The `string_detect` is a bit much for this example, but some real-world values are long strings, so it can easily pick them.

It simple to run cross tabs on the data when recoded this way.

I have other cases were I wanted to recode categorical data within the same variable. `mutate` with `case_when` was very useful for that.